# Python Import From Module

Tags: python, module

I know this question has been asked many times in the similiar fashion but I want to understand the `import` mechanism of **Python** in the simplest example.

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

> .\Project\moduleOne.py
>
> .\Project\moduleTwo.py

Basically I import a function from `moduleTwo` while being in `moduleOne`:

```
from moduleTwo import myFunction
```

Everything works as intended, I can use `myFunction`. However, if I change the `import` statement, like below:

```
from .moduleTwo import MyFunction
```

I receive the following error:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Even if I have a `__init__.py` file to make a project directory a package I still receive the same error.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This might help https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that the current directory when you do this is *.\Project*, and that you are running

```
python3 moduleOne.py
```

You are therefore importing `moduleTwo` as an independent module rather than as a submodule of a package.

If you were, for example, to ascend the directory hierarchy so that your current directory is the *Project* directory's parent, and execute

```
python3 -m Project.moduleOne
```

you will find that the relative import from `.moduleTwo` executes perfectly well.